# Do you know what might be causing parts of website to dissapear?

Tags: css, particles.js

From some reason on computer only, the very top section of website with navbar and my name dissapears when I scroll down, wait a bit and go fast back up. Do you know what might be causing this? I wonder if it is something with particles.js(which are used in the background) because I haven't experienced this before. Thanks in advance.

[netlify website](https://janlinhart.netlify.app/)

[full code](https://github.com/JanLinhart/Portfolio-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like adding `z-index: -1;` to `#particles-js` (your background) is fixint it.

Comment: omg thanks so much, it really is working